# How to use API AI in production?

Tags: api-ai

I'm thinking about building production version of a chatbot basing on API AI.

I found couple of links but without good answers (I cannot post them due to too low reputation).

Here's the list of questions:

1. **How to hande platform updates?**
   Are there any notifications before the API AI platform gets updated? Is there any test environment where the upgraded platform can be tested before hitting production?
2. **How to setup non-PROD environments (e.g. dev/stage/prod)?** Is there any other option than setting multiple accounts and manually exporting/importing agents configuration between them?
3. **What's the cost of using API AI commercially?** According to the https://api.ai/pricing/ the usage of the services is free.
   Are there any limits regarding the traffic that can be handled by free version? Are there any paid plans for API for commercial usage?

Answer (score 0):

1. Before any updates there will be notifications via email
2. If you want to setup different agents you can export the agent (as a zip) and restore it to another agent.  This would allow you to test and agent and validate it and then move it to your "production" agent when you are ready
3. Api.ai is free to use, if you're going to send a lot of traffic all at once or are interested in a SLA/SLO or other information Api.ai has a contact page regarding pricing: https://api.ai/pricing/

Comment: Thanks @matthewayne, but it answers my questions partially. The notifications are sent indeed, but I haven't found any information about the place where planned updates could be tested. I know about the import/export option, my question was about different possibilities.

Comment: Currently there is no way to test planned updates.  Can you expand in "different possibilities"?  What kinds of things are you looking for? Can you expand on your use case?

Comment: Thanks @matthewayne. Regarding "different possibilities" - I thought about an automatic migration of agent settings to different agent without a necessity of manual exporting and importing from zip file. This would be useful if I had different agents simulating different environments (test, prod) and wanted to promote the settings to higher environment.